# Вывод 2D с поворотом в Irrlicht

Tags: c++, 2d, irrlicht, rotate

Возможно ли это?

Не могу найти информацию по этому вопросу в документации и в примерах. Неужели, чтобы вывести повернутое 2D изображение необходимо использовать 3D полигон с натянутой на него текстурой?

Comment: Повёрнутой по какой оси?

Comment: Если относительно z - это простое вращение, а если по двум другим, то нужно уточнить что вы хотите: перспективное или афинное преобразование.

Comment: Я хочу повернуть двумерное изображение по часовой или против часовой стрелки.

Comment: ну так и зачем вам трехмерный полигон для этого случая? Это же типичное афинное преобразование: используйте матрицу поворота. PS это поворот относительно z

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, мне интересует, есть ли в `Irrlicht` примитивы и методы для вывода `2D` с поворотом. Как это сделать вне `Irrlicht` (например, в `OpenGL`) мне хорошо известно.

Comment: этого я не знаю, но было бы весьма странно для простейшего афинного преобразования использовать трехмерный полигон